# How do I extract the first x lines from a large CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv

How do I extract the first 100,000 lines from a large CSV file (1GB+) using only Powershell on a Windows machine?

Comment: How is this question off-topic? I'm asking how to write a Powershell script to complete a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the below answer was marked as not helpful when it answers the question.

```
-TotalCount<Int64>
Gets the specified number of lines from the beginning of a file or other item. The default is -1 (all lines).
You can use the "TotalCount" parameter name or its aliases, "First" or "Head".
```

The performance of the command can be improved by

```
Get-Content -TotalCount 100000 -ReadCount 0 filename.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content -TotalCount 100000 filename.csv`